# java key listener doesn't work with multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

I have a JFrame with 1 panel for drawing and set KyeListener for JFrame. It works fine unless I add JTextArea or JTextPane. Looks like it stops responding at all. I need some option to display the text and use keylistener for animation. I don't need anything to type, I just want my keylistener working all the time. I need something better than JLabel, I want some formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) isn't designated for listening `KeyEvents` came from keyboard to the Swing GUI,
2. because KeyListener required focusable `JComponent`, you have to set for `setFocusable()` or programatically moving with `Focus`
3. `Focus / Focus SubSystem` is asynchonous
4. use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather that bothering with [Focus / Focus SubSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't just add the KeyListener to the panel itself?

```
panel.addKeyListener(this);
```